# Windows phone application does not work properly when I'm trying to call a web api

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing a simple windows phone 8 application.
I do not use `MVVM`, it is very simple.
I have a button, and when I press it I want to add some data into the database (using the post method).
The web `API` is made in `asp.net` and it works properly because I tested with `fiddler`, and also with a console application.
The code behind from the button is the following:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string baseUrl = "myWebApiLink";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string serviceUrl;
        serviceUrl = "api/People";

        var anEmployee = new People()
         {
             FirstName = "Windows",
             LastName = "Phone",
             Age = 8
         };
         HttpResponseMessage response;
         response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result; //the problem
         if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             //some success messages
         }
         else
         {
             //some fail messages
         }
UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

At the line

```
response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result;
```

the application just gets blocked.
It does not throw an exception, it just stays on that line.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you try to make your button click event async and use await on postasjsonAsync. e.g.

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
....

response = awiat client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee)

Comment: It checked out and it is included.

Comment: Have you tried `response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee);`?

Comment: It solves somehow the problem, now the application does not stop anymore. but id does not add to database.

Comment: Have you tried to set breakpoints after the await line? What is the result content?

Comment: Yes. The esponse.IsSuccesStatusCoed is false because the URI is not found. The API still works, i tested the code above in that console application.

Comment: Then it seems that your URl where you post data is not correct, How it look like?

Comment: I don't have any URI, just this URL: "http://localhost:50902/" from string baseUrl = "http://localhost:50902/"; And the asp.net api is running this time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use async button client and await on post async call... here is how.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string baseUrl = "myWebApiLink";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    string serviceUrl;
    serviceUrl = "api/People";
    var anEmployee = new People()
     {
         FirstName = "Windows",
         LastName = "Phone",
         Age = 8
     };
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //some success messages
    }
    else
    {
        //some fail messages
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the line   response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result; generate the following error: Cannot await 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'. I can erase the ".Result" it works but it does not add to the database.

Comment: I found the problem. I published the website and I unlocked my port. I don't have enough badges to rate up your answer so I will just say thanks for your support! :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually i dont think it says on that line, you are calling an asynchronous method, which means your code continues executing and does not wait for the response. Changing the method signature by adding async, and then awaiting the respoonse from the call will work. Here is your code modified.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string baseUrl = "myWebApiLink/";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        string serviceUrl;
        serviceUrl = "api/People";

        var anEmployee = new People()
        {
            FirstName = "Windows",
            LastName = "Phone",
            Age = 8
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, serviceUrl);
        var requestContent = anEmployee; //this value is a string, check the format on your server

        request.Content = new StringContent(requestContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = await client.SendAsync(request); //no longer the problem

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //some success messages
        }
        else
        {
            //some fail messages
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the line   response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result; generate the following error: Cannot await 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'. I can erase the ".Result" it works but it does not add to the database.

Comment: i have made some changes to the code, now using HttpRequestMessage to send the POST parameters. The only other issue i for see is the value of anEmployee and how you are expecting to receive it on your server. Format it as a json string if that is what the server is expecting.

Comment: Acctualy response.IsSuccesStatusCode is false. That is probably because I erased the .Result from the line response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(serviceUrl, anEmployee).Result. If I don't erarse the .Result I get an error: Cannot await 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage'

Comment: I found the problem. I published the website and I unlocked my port. I don't have enough badges to rate up your answer so I will just thank you all for your support! :) It was very helpful!